# Vectorize logical indexing

Tags: numpy, indexing, vectorization

I have an image with three channels. I also have a mask that randomly extracts the same number of pixels from each channel (but not necessarily the same across channels).

Is it possible to vectorize that extracting process, that is, the loop over the channels?

Here is what I'm trying to do in an unvectorized way:

My hunch so far is that it is not possible via the masking, as it is a priori not clear that each of the mask has the same number of `True` values.

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(0)
# set up image
img = np.random.random((3, 100, 111))

# set up some mask with same number of "True" pixels per channel
p = 0.3
mask_array = np.stack([np.random.permutation(np.prod(img.shape[1:])).reshape(img.shape[1:]) > p for _ in range(img.shape[0])], axis=0)
print(mask_array.shape) # same as img.shape

# can we vectorize the loop over k away?
output = np.stack([img[k, mask_array[k, ...]] for k in range(img.shape[0])], axis=0)

print(output.shape)  # img.shape[0] x N
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply the mask to your image will result in a flattened array. You can then reshape the result:

```
vector_output = img[mask_array].reshape((3, -1))

assert np.allclose(output, vector_output) # Assertion succeeds
```

Comment: My bad! It's hidden away in the `allclose`. I was looking at `output`, and didn't realize you did that just for the `allclose` calculation. Sorry about that

Comment: but actually, your answer was better, and the other reshapes are unnecessary

Comment: Since it's basically the same as yours, I edited your answer :)

Comment: You might consider removing the setup code since it's functionally identical to OP's. I edited the question to change the `np.zeros()` call to `np.random.random` since that's probably what OP intended anyway

Comment: That's a clever idea, thank you both for the excellent answer!